# Problems rendering map position with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been following along with a LibGDX tutorial on Youtube and have come across an issue rendering a TiledMap to my screen. At the moment, I can render some labels/images using my HUD java class

```
public class HUD {
public Stage stage; //the background
private Viewport viewport; //so the HUD stays fixed and the world can move
private int score;
private int timer;
private int bactoCount;
private Texture foodTexture, antioBioBottle;

//these are widgets
Label antioBioTxt;
Image antiBioImg;
Label countDown;
Label countTxt;
Image foodImg;
Label foodTxt;
Label bactoCountLabel;
Label bactoTxt;
//these images need to be buttons...


public HUD (SpriteBatch sb) {
    foodTexture = new Texture("Bacto food.png");
    antioBioBottle = new Texture("Antibioticbottle.png");
    bactoCount = 0;
    timer = 0;
    viewport = new FitViewport(BactoBuds.V_WIDTH, BactoBuds.V_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());

    stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);
    //stage = new Stage();
    //use a Table to organise widgets on the stage

    Table table = new Table();
    table.top();
    table.setFillParent(true); //the table is the size of our stage

    antioBioTxt = new Label("Antibiotic", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    antiBioImg = new Image(antioBioBottle);



    // %03d means its 3 digits long
    //bitmap font sets the font to bit style
    //string.format for changing from a string to a int

    countDown = new Label(String.format("%03d", timer), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    countTxt = new Label("Time to flood:", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));

    foodImg = new Image(foodTexture);
    foodTxt = new Label("Food", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));

    bactoCountLabel = new Label(String.format("%06d", bactoCount), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    bactoTxt = new Label("Bacteria:", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));

    //if multiple labels use expandX then they all share an equal portion of the screen

    table.add(antioBioTxt).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(foodTxt).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(bactoTxt).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(countTxt).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.row();
    table.add(antiBioImg).expandX();
    table.add(foodImg).expandX();
    table.add(bactoCountLabel).expandX().align(Align.center);
    table.add(countDown).expandX().align(Align.center);

    stage.addActor(table);


}
```

}

These render nicely on the screen. However, when I try to render up a background TMX map image, it renders in the wrong location. I've been messing with the code for a few days now, trying to change the position of the map position. At the first instance I was only able to see a tiny corner of the map and now I've gotten the whole thing to render, but it only takes up ~1/4 of the screen. Now I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

```
public class playScreen implements Screen{
private BactoBuds game;
private OrthographicCamera gamecamera;
private Viewport gameView;
private HUD HUD;
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader; //loads map to screen
private TiledMap map; //reference to map
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;




public playScreen (BactoBuds game) {
    this.game = game;



    gamecamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    gameView = new FitViewport(BactoBuds.V_WIDTH, BactoBuds.V_HEIGHT, gamecamera);

    HUD = new HUD(game.batch);

    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader(); //make a new map loader, set map to maploader, then pass it to the renderer
    map = mapLoader.load("grassy.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);


    gamecamera.setToOrtho(false);
    gamecamera.position.set(gameView.getWorldWidth() / 2, gameView.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0); //this changes map position
    renderer.setView(gamecamera);

}


@Override
public void show() {

}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(HUD.stage.getCamera().combined);

    HUD.stage.draw();


}
```

Please forgive the dodgy coding, I'm quite new and I'm still learning about good practices. I think it has something to do with the camera positioning, but swapping out the values doesn't appear to change anything.

```
public class BactoBuds extends Game {
public static final int V_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int V_HEIGHT = 480;
public static final String Title = "BactoBuds";
public SpriteBatch batch; //public to let other screens have access to images
private Texture img;
private Game game;
private Screen screen;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

public BactoBuds () {
    game = this;

}



@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    // change this to menuScreen later
    setScreen(new playScreen(this));


}

public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render () {

    super.render();
}

public void resume (){

}

public void pause () {

}
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How large is your TiledMap? If you need to scale. You can set a scale in the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer constructor

Comment: Thanks for replying. I ended up changing the background image to a texture, but if I change the code back, I'll be sure to give the scaling ago. I remember attempting to use a scaledViewPort or some such to no avail. 

When setting the "float unitScale" is that typically written as something like 2 or 2f? or do I need to declare it before I use it? (Sorry, for the noob question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call camera.update() within render method.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried adding gamecamera.update() to the render method and then to the playscreen method in the playscreen java class. However this did not change the position of the background map. I then added camera.update() to the render method in my main BactoBuds java class, but it just crashes the app with a "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your camera?  If only 1/4 of the map is visible your camera might be centered at 0,0 while your map uses that as the bottom left origin of the texture.

Try    camera.position.set(BactoBuds.V_WIDTH / 2, BactoBuds.V_HEIGHT / 2, 0);